# Behaviour of serializable transactions in oracle?

Tags: java, oracle

I have below  sequence of transaction  with isolation level as serializable

```
 trnsaction1                               transaction2

                                           get row2   // value1

 update row1
 update row2//update to 2
 commit

                                           get row1
                                           get row2 //  lin6
```

will transaction 2 see the updated value of row 1 and row 2. Sure that transaction2 will not see the updated value of row2(update by transaction 1) at line6 but not sure will it see the updated value of row1 updated by transaction1?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once transaction1 commits its work, transaction 2 will see the updated changes in both of the last two lines. That is, unless you do `SET TRANSACTION READ ONLY` as the very first action in your transaction.

In a read-write transaction, individual statements are read-consistent, but not between multiple statements.

Edit:

steve, I believe that's incorrect. From the [documentation](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B14117_01/server.101/b10743/consist.htm#i17841):

[Read commited transaction]

> This is the default transaction isolation level. Each query executed
>   by a transaction sees only data that was committed before the query
>   (not the transaction) began. An Oracle query never reads dirty
>   (uncommitted) data.
>
> Because Oracle does not prevent other transactions
>   from modifying the data read by a query, that data can be changed by
>   other transactions between two executions of the query. Thus, a
>   transaction that runs a given query twice can experience both
>   nonrepeatable read and phantoms.

[Serializable]

> Serializable transactions see only those changes that were committed
>   at the time the transaction began, plus those changes made by the
>   transaction itself through INSERT, UPDATE, and DELETE statements.
>   Serializable transactions do not experience nonrepeatable reads or
>   phantoms.

Comment: hi eaolson, line 6 in transaction2  will not see the commited value by  transaction1 .Because serializable transaction transaction dont allow non repeatable read. Thats for sure. But i am concerned about get row1 above line 6

Comment: It will return the value of row1 at the time when transaction 2 started

Comment: Thanks steve.So basically serializable transaction will have kind of snapshot of schema when transaction start and will return the rows from that snapshot even data got commited by some other transaction. Right?

Comment: @Steve: You should make that an answer, not a comment. Ideally, with an explanation of how MVCC makes that happen.

Comment: Yes it uses the consistent read mechanism with a snapshot SCN.